# Help unbricking my nexus 5

Tags: nexus-5, bootloader, partitions, nexus

let me tell a story first, i want to flash new boot.img for my nexus 5, but i'm also curious what happen if i do re-partition. I delete boot partition `./parted /dev/block/mmcblk0 rm 19` (my boot is 19) then restart it without reformat or even making the partition. Now my nexus 5 can't boot into system or recovery but can boot to bootloader. Search here there, no answers until i have an idea, flash the stock ROM, since it's ok in bootloader i think it is fine if i flash my phone with stock ROM via fastboot, then i do it. After the CMD show results finish flashing bootloader and then restart bootloader, now my nexus 5 won't turn on like no power at all.

Please help this moron, my nexus 5 is the only phone i have and i don't have money if i must buy new phone or even change the nexus 5 board